# jQuery Validator - validate value in data attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, custom-data-attribute

I am writing a credit card field with a mask on it, but saving the actual untouched number to the element's data attribute. This way the credit card number "6011000000000004" is stored for use but "601100******0004" is displayed on the screen.

Using jQuery Validator, is there a way to validate that field based on the data attribute?

In my form I have

```
<input type="text" id="creditcard" />
```

then when a user changes the value, it creates a mask and saves the value to `$("#creditcard").data("cc_number")` like:

```
$(document).on("keyup paste drop", "#creditcard", function() {
    // Copy the super secret old cc value */    
    var old_cc = $(this).data("cc_number") || "";

    // Copy the masked value 
    var this_val = $(this).val();

    /* If there is a value and it is less than the max create a mask */ 
    if (this_val.length > 0 && this_val.length <= 16) {
        // If the stored number is less than the new value, 
        // append the last entered character to the stored value.
        // If not make the masked cc # the same as the stored value     
        var cc = (old_cc.length < this_val.length ? old_cc + this_val.substring(this_val.length -1, this_val.length) : old_cc.substring(0,this_val.length));

    // Copy the new cc value to the super secret field
    $(this).data("cc_number", cc);

    /* Code that builds cc_mask
     *  removed to make it easier to read
     */
    
    // Sets #creditcard value to the mask
    $(this).val(cc_mask);

}

// I don't think we need to do this but since I already have it here...
return false;
});
```

Is there a way to override jQuery validator to validate on the value of `$("#creditcard".data("cc_number");`?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own rule.

Basically I copied the built in creditcard rule, but made it grab the data element I wanted to listen to:

```
/* rule to validate a certain data attribute */
jQuery.validator.addMethod("creditcard_from_datafield", function(value, element, param) {
if ( this.optional(element) ) {
            return "dependency-mismatch";
        }
        value = $(element).data("cc-number");


        // accept only spaces, digits and dashes
        if ( /[^0-9 \-]+/.test(value) ) {
            return false;
        }
        var nCheck = 0,
            nDigit = 0,
            bEven = false;

        value = value.replace(/\D/g, "");

        for (var n = value.length - 1; n >= 0; n--) {
            var cDigit = value.charAt(n);
            nDigit = parseInt(cDigit, 10);
            if ( bEven ) {
                if ( (nDigit *= 2) > 9 ) {
                    nDigit -= 9;
                }
            }
            nCheck += nDigit;
            bEven = !bEven;
        }

        return (nCheck % 10) === 0; 
});
```